# Windows Form App Deployment/Installation

Tags: windows, winforms

I have a Windows form app that I've published but the end result is not what I've expected. After the wizard finishes, I click on the setup.exe and the application installs and launches, but I don't see any shortcuts in the All Programs. The application is listed in Programs and Features but when I close the app, there is no icon to click to launch it again. I've searched for an executable file in the Program Files and System32 folders found nothing.

So what I wanted to to do is create a desktop shrtcut, or shortcut in the All Programs as part of the installation process.

Also how do I assign a custom icon that will show up in the task bar?

Thanks,
Risho

Comment: By 'published' do you mean published as a ClickOnce app? If not, what installer technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason, Visual Studio used the registered name under which it was installed, which is my employer, to create a shortcut on the All Programs and dropped the program shortcut there.

I also found in the project property page where to set the desktop icon.

Man, I'm good - sheesh! (JK)

Have great day.

Answer (score 2):

[create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step](http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/)

Is very helpful link for new users. Wpf and windows Forms are not much different in Deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about ClickOnce publishing, you can ensure that desktop shortcuts and start menu shortcuts are created by selecting the 'The application is available offline as well (launchable from start menu)' radio button in the publish tab of the project properties, and clicking the 'Create desktop shortcut' checkbox in the Publish Options window.

Comment: I do web stuff, so this is first, and first with VS2010. I select Publish from the Debug menu. It'll ask me where I want to publish, for simplicity, I give it the path to a desktop folder. Next, it get three option and I just go with the default (Form CD-ROM). After that it asks about updates, I go with the default (No updates) and after that it's ready to publish to my selected location. I don't get any option you mentioned.